# data.table: calculate cumulative percentile for all numeric variables

Tags: r, data.table, numeric, percentile

I have data like this

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(id = c("A", "A", "B", "B","C", "C"), 
             var1 = c(1:6),
             var2 = rnorm(6))

> dt
   id var1       var2
1:  A    1 -0.6264538
2:  A    2  0.1836433
3:  B    3 -0.8356286
4:  B    4  1.5952808
5:  C    5  0.3295078
6:  C    6 -0.8204684
```

but **with dozens of numeric variables**. I'd like to calculate percentile for each observation and every numeric variable using `data.table`, while keeping a key identifier (`id`) intact. In `dplyr` I could do it like this:

```
mutate_if(dt, is.numeric, function(x) { ecdf(x)(x) })

  id      var1      var2
1  A 0.1666667 0.5000000
2  A 0.3333333 0.6666667
3  B 0.5000000 0.1666667
4  B 0.6666667 1.0000000
5  C 0.8333333 0.8333333
6  C 1.0000000 0.3333333
```

I would be also happy with the result including original `var1` and `var2`.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Don't have time to explain but this should give you what you want without the id column: `dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) ecdf(x)(x)), .SDcols = sapply(dt, is.numeric)]`. You can then `cbind` the id column afterward.

Comment: Try `mutate_at(dat, vars(starts_with("var")), function(x) { ecdf(x)(x) })` or `mutate_if(dat, is.numeric, function(x) { ecdf(x)(x) })`

Comment: @jav, is there a way of keeping `id` in the result? simple cbinding gives me inaccurate results compared to the original data, for some reason

Comment: @StevenBeaupré: that would do the trick, but I'm working with millions of observations, so for that reason I need to do it in `data.table`...

Comment: @Frank: good point, will edit my post now

Comment: @KasiaKulma you could try the following. First make a copy:
`dt2 = copy(dt)`. Then find which columns are numeric: `numCols = which(sapply(dt2, is.numeric))`. And finally transform `dt2` as follows: `dt2[, (numCols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ecdf(x)(x)), .SDcols = numCols]`. It will transform the numeric columns and leave the `id` column intact.

Comment: And in case you don't want to overwrite the cols, jav's answer/comment can be modified to `dt[, paste0("ptl_", cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) ecdf(x)(x)), .SDcols=cols][]`

Comment: thanks, @Frank, that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the `ecdf` for all numeric columns in a separate data table like this:

```
dt2 = as.data.table(lapply(dt,function(x){if(is.numeric(x)){ecdf(x)(x)}}))
```

Result:

```
> dt2
        var1      var2
1: 0.1666667 0.8333333
2: 0.3333333 0.3333333
3: 0.5000000 0.6666667
4: 0.6666667 1.0000000
5: 0.8333333 0.1666667
6: 1.0000000 0.5000000
```

If you want to `cbind` this result to the original dt, you could change the column names using `paste0`:

```
colnames(dt2) = paste0("centile_",colnames(dt2))
```

Result:

```
> dt2
   centile_var1 centile_var2
1:    0.1666667    0.8333333
2:    0.3333333    0.3333333
3:    0.5000000    0.6666667
4:    0.6666667    1.0000000
5:    0.8333333    0.1666667
6:    1.0000000    0.5000000
```

Comment: thanks for that! It does ALMOST exactly what I need: your result doesn't contain `id` and if I simply try to `cbind` it I get results different from the original data. Is there a way of keeping it in the result?

Comment: Just add and `else` statement at the end: `as.data.table(lapply(dt,function(x){if(is.numeric(x)){ecdf(x)(x)} else x}))`.